# Simplify SQL query for repeating formula in an update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My current query is as below

```
UPDATE A
SET Computation = CASE WHEN Type = 'P' THEN
                           B.X * A.Y *-1
                  ELSE
                           B.X * A.Y
END
FROM table A
INNER JOIN table B
ON A.Link = B.Link
```

If its possible, how can I optimize it by only showing the formula B.X * A.Y once in my query? Or actually in performance wise this query is good enough?

Comment: To determine performance inspect the execution plan.

Comment: `B.X * A.Y - CASE ... THEN -1 ELSE 0 END`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bring `B.X * A.Y` outside of case statement:

```
(CASE 
  WHEN Type = 'P' THEN -1
  ELSE 1
 end
)*B.X * A.Y
```

Your query:

```
UPDATE A
SET Computation = (CASE WHEN Type = 'P' THEN -1
                  ELSE 1 END
                  )*B.X * A.Y
FROM table A
INNER JOIN table B
ON A.Link = B.Link
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` any time you wish to use the results of a calculation more than once.

```
UPDATE A
  SET Computation = CASE WHEN Type = 'P' THEN X.Value * -1 ELSE X.Value END
FROM table A
INNER JOIN table B B.?? = ON A.??
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (B.X * A.Y)) X (Value)
```

For a simple calculation such as this its unlikely to make much difference to performance (check the execution plan and see). But personally from a readability and maintainability perspective I like having my calculations in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor to simplify for readability but performance should be similar

```
UPDATE A
SET Computation = IIF(Type = 'P', -1, 1) * B.X * A.Y
FROM table A
INNER JOIN table B
ON A.Link = B.Link
```